# Access to config in static method

Tags: php, phalcon

How can I get access to config in static method of controller? I have Phalcon 1.3 . This method is not working:

```
$offerSource = $this->config->offerSource;
```

Comment: `$this` does not exist in a static method, as no instances need to exist for the static method to be called. Why do you have a static method on a controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This!

**Accessing the DI in a static way**

If needed you can access the latest DI created in a static function You can use `\Phalcon\DI::getDefault()` in static method. [More Info](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/di.html#accessing-the-di-in-a-static-way)

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->StaticMethod();
}

private static function StaticMethod()
{
    $config = \Phalcon\DI::getDefault()['config']->toArray();
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($config);
    echo "</pre>";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: @sdafasdf Please Vote the answer!

Comment: It's better to use `$config = \Phalcon\DI::getDefault()->get('config')`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned pseudovariable $this is not allowed in static methods. You may declare config property as static and then access it in static methods like that: self::$config

Comment: How can I declare config static property? I don't know how to do it without $this.

Comment: Add keyword "static" to config property declaration, so (assuming that config has protected visibility) it will look like that: protected static $config;

Comment: But how I can get access to config's attributes placed in app/config/config.php ?

Comment: app/config/config.php must be a part of Phalcon 1.3, so don't change there anything. In that case only instances of class can access to $config, so don't use static but non-static method.